# python splitting numbers in a column

Tags: python, parsing, split

Please help explain how to do the following, I am struggling so much.

I have a data set named data3:

- Type (column1) = string values of GTIN or GCP
- Key (column2) = 14 digit numbers

I need to break those 14 digit numbers up into this logic:

- if `type = GCP` then return first three letters from key.
- if `type = GTIN` and positions 2-6 in the 14 digits = 00000 then return positions 7-9 in key.
- if `type = gtin` and positions 2-6 are not 00000 then return digits 2-4 in key .

EXAMPLE:

```
 - Type       -Key    
 - GTIN       -1234589564652344 
 - GCP        -1564546545452344 
 - GTIN       -6000005645324234
```

If the type is GCP I just want first three numbers in key such as 156.
If it's GTIN and has 5 zeros in postitions 2-6 I want positions 7-9 which would be 564 in.

If the type is GTIN and does not have  5 zeros in positions 2-6 then I want to return digits 2-4 such as 234 in the above example

Comment: could you provide a sample of your data ?

Comment: just did please help thanks

Comment: It is still not clear from your example what the format of your data is. Please show actual columns. Are the dashes part of the file too?

Comment: dashes are not part of the file  I did that to show list on here. format ? what do you mean its in rows and columns with Type and Key as the column headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following using `apply` function:

```
# create function based on values
def get_values(row):

    if row['Type']  == 'GCP':
        return row['Key'][:3]
    elif row['Type'] == 'GTIN' and row['Key'][1:6] == '00000':
        return row['Key'][6:9]
    elif row['Type'] == 'GTIN' and row['Key'][2:7] != '00000':
        return row['Key'][1:4]

# convert to string
df['Key'] = df['Key'].astype(str)

# now use apply function
df['new'] = df.apply(get_values, axis=1)

   Type               Key  new
0  GTIN  1234589564652344  234
1   GCP  1564546545452344  156
2  GTIN  6000005645324234  564
```

Comment: happy to help, please accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: that answer was fire, easy to understand and made a complex problem simple.

Answer (score 0):

You did a good work breaking down the logic to 3 ifs.

Now break each if into little pieces of code. The first one is easy:

```
if type == "GCP":
    return key[:3]
```

What are you not able to code ?

Comment: SyntaxError: 'return' outside function. That's the error I got when I used that code

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are stored as strings you can split the very easily in python. You can split strings using the index of the characters you want. For example if you want to get the first three characters out of a string you could do

```
key[:3]
```

This would give you everything up to but not including the character in the 3 position. To pull characters out of the middle you could use

```
key[1:6]
```

This would give you all the numbers starting at the 1 spot until the 6 spot. (remember that the index starts at 0)

If you wanted to check the middle of the string to see if it is equal to something try something like this:

```
if key[1:6] == "00000":
    #do something
```

This will compare the part of the string between 1 and 6 to see if it is equal to "00000".

Comment: only problem is when I convert key to strings I get errors, what forumas would you use

Comment: How are you converting them to strings? you could just use `str(key)`

Comment: @grim_reaper `str(key)` doesn't permanently change it to a string you would have to do `if str(key)[1:6] == "00000":` every time